# MySQL - How to replace a string with a random string from a list

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I know how to replace a string using a query like:

```
UPDATE  `postmeta` SET  `meta_value` = REPLACE(`meta_value`, 'old_string', 'replacement')
```

What I want to do is for Mysql to choose a random string from a list of strings, sort of like this:

```
UPDATE  `postmeta` SET  `meta_value` = REPLACE(`meta_value`, 'old_string', RAND(['replacement','replacement2','replacement3']))
```

OR

I would like for it to cycle through the list instead of choose them randomly...
eg: Replace the first record with 'replacement', second record with 'replacement2', fourth record with 'replacement'...

Is this sort of query possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [ELT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) function. `ELT()` returns the *N* th element of a list of strings: str1 if *N* = 1, str2 if *N* = 2, and so on:

```sql
UPDATE `postmeta` 
SET `meta_value` = REPLACE(`meta_value`, 'old_string', 
  ELT(1 + RAND() * 3, 'replacement', 'replacement2', 'replacement3'))
```

Comment: Alright this is great but while writing the question, I had another idea. Say the query will update 200 rows. Is there any way to get the number of the row being currently updated? I would be able to cycle through the list instead of randomly selecting using (current_iteration % length_of_list +1) in ELT.

Comment: That's trickier. I would suggest reading [this article](http://www.independent-software.com/mysql-stored-procedure-return-every-nth-row.html) for a few pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rand()` and a `case` expression:

```
update `postmeta` 
set `meta_value` = replace(
    `meta_value`, 
    'old_string',
    case floor(1 + rand() * 2) 
        when 1 then 'replacement'
        when 2 then 'replacement2'
        when 3 then 'replacement3'
    end
);
```

`floor(1 + rand() * 2)` generates a random value between 1 and 3 (see [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) for more details).

Answer (score 1):

Use can use the `elt()` function and `rand()`:

```
UPDATE postmeta
    SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'old_string', 
                             ELT(FLOOR(RAND() * 3 + 1, 'replacement', 'replacement2', 'replacement3')
                            );
```

If you don't want to actually *replace* part of the string, but want to assign the *whole* string, then I think you want:

```
UPDATE postmeta
    SET meta_value = ELT(FLOOR(RAND() * 3 + 1, 'replacement', 'replacement2', 'replacement3')
    WHERE meta_value = 'old_string';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//you could use ran() for example of my own:
CREATE TABLE RandomFirstNames (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(...),
    PRIMARY KEY(id) )
SELECT first_name FROM FirstNames ORDER BY RAND();
```